# Using XAMPP to send mail using PHP mail() (Having trouble getting it to work)

Tags: php, email, xampp

I have read similar posts about the same issue and have tried troubleshooting the problem, but it does not seem to work. I have Windows 8 64 bit and I am running XAMPP version 1.8.3.

This is the code for [mail function] in php.ini

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\web\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\web\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the  C:\web\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\web\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
; mail.log = "C:\web\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

The sendmail_path should be correct. I commented out the sendmail_path with maildisk. There is a warning that there should not be any spaces in the names of the file directory, and I don't think this applies to me.Also, there is a php.ini-development and php.ini-production file in the php directory of XAMPP and I want to make sure that these should not be modified.

This is the code for sendmail.ini:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=email@gmail.com
auth_password=password

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

I want to confirm the port should be 587. I am using a gmail account to send the emails. I am wondering if any changes need to be made to the setting of gmail to allow this program to access it and send email?

This is the test code I am trying to run as per the php page on the mail() function:

```
<?php
    $to      = 'example@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: example@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: example@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "sent";
    } else {
        echo "not sent";
    }
?>
```

Is it okay that I am trying to send to a yahoo email? Is it possible that there is a small detail that I am getting wrong (like spaces or minor syntax detail)? I am including $headers because I read that it is required. Also, is there any way to get an error directly from php which tells me why the mail() returned false?

Update: 
I added the following code to php.ini and now it seems I can see the errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

I am getting the following error:

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\web\xampp\htdocs\arctic\mail.php on line 29

(this is the line with my mail() function)

I set the port to 587 in sendmail.ini. Do I also have to set this in php.ini?

Also, I just started the Mercury module on my XAMPP control panel and now I get a different error:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry. in C:\web\xampp\htdocs\arctic\mail.php on line 29

I realize this is a long question and I thank anyone in advance for their help!